# NServiceBus Windows-Service: Service can't be stopped

Tags: c#, windows-services, nservicebus

I have the problem, that since some time, we can't stop a NServiceBus Windows-Service. If we try to, we get this exception:

> Error 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.

Unfortunately, I really didn't find anything about this matter but this Github-Issue: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1898

Sadly, this doesn't help, since we need in fact the `IConfigureThisEndpoint` Interface, to configure the `BusConfiguration`, which also isn't that long running. We also use almost the exact same template for other NServiceBus-Endpoints, which don't have any problems.

Interesting enough, it worked also for this Endpoint for quite some time and it also seem also to be a problem only for one specific Server.

Is there a possibility to find more about the exception, be it from Microsoft or NServiceBus?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on another server? What version of NServiceBus are you running? Are you using the host?

Comment: Hi, at the moment I couldnt reproduce it on any other Server, We use the 5.2.8 Version of NServiceBus, with RavenDB and MSMQ. And yes, as far as I know the windows-service is the host shell behind, or could you elaborate what you mean with "using the host"?

Comment: By just I mean nservicebus.host.exe

Comment: Sorry, can't edit my comment,: By the Host i mean NServiceBus.host.exe

Answer (score 1):

## Graceful shutdown

This error can be caused for a lot of reasons. NServiceBus will only try to perform a graceful shutdown.

NServiceBus will not abort messages that are currently being processed but will stop processing new messages.

## Log file

The log file should indicate that a shutdown is triggered so that is the first thing you can verify.

I would advise to set the log level to DEBUG to help diagnose the shutdown sequence and to also add this:

```
var appDomainLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("AppDomain");
var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
appDomain.FirstChanceException += (o, ea) => { 
    appDomainLogger.Debug("FirstChanceException", ea.Exception);
};
appDomain.UnhandledException += (o, ea) => { 
    appDomainLogger.Debug("UnhandledException", ea.ExceptionObject as Exception); 
};
```

It could be that exceptions occur that prevent shutdown and this adds additional diagnostics.

## Long running messages

If for example a message is being processed that is waiting for a lock on a database to be released then this message could take more time then the windows service interface allows.

Other tasks like converting media files

Eventually, the windows service should shutdown if all resources are freed and messages are done processing unless they contain a bug that prevents shutdown.

## Disposing of resources

Also, during shutdown the container is disposed too. It might be that your container has resources that have lots of cleanup/teardown to do. For example, resources that flush in-memory caches to disk or remote storage so the next time the services is started it can startup faster then normal.

Comment: Many thanks for the insights, I will check it out. This is the only Host we're using Sagas with, probably that might also come into play.